# Do I need to have a restore purchase button for in app purchases? or can I handle it on my own using a server?

Tags: xcode, in-app-purchase, apple-developer

I have done my research and found that apple will reject your app if it does not have a restore button.

I have tried this code to restore purchases:

SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()

The problem that I face is that the user may have different accounts that they log into on the same device. So when I restore the purchase it does not necessarily look at the current user but rather the device as a whole.

My idea was to use a server to store whether the user has made a purchase. So now I have user specific information and do not need to have a restore button as I can re update their purchases when they get on a new device. (It's also important to note that my app is using non consumable purchases.) Will this work? more importantly, will my app get accepted by apple?

Answer (score 3):

**3.1.1 In-App Purchase:** "Any credits or in-game currencies purchased via in-app purchase may not expire, and you should make sure you have a restore mechanism for any restorable in-app purchases." https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

You are required to have a restore mechanism inside the app, this is a convention users are used to seeing. In addition to this, it acts as a rescue mechanism should you experience an issue server side. You face a rejection if you do not include this.